# String concatenation in Java gives null together with first result

Tags: java, null, string-concatenation

When i run a query with `mysqlconnector` and fetching the result with `ResulSet` my first is always with an `null` before.

This my code:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    conn =DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/","","");
    String query = "SELECT Category,Account FROM Settings" ;//
    PreparedStatement select = conn.prepareStatement(query);
    ResultSet rs = select.executeQuery( );

    while (rs.next())
        {

                category += rs.getString("Category")+",";
                account += rs.getString("Account")+",";
```

And my result is always: `nullresult, result, result...`

Even when its only one result it is always: nullResult

How can i fix this?

Comment: provide the full method and i can say anything!!

Answer (score 3):

you may have declared `null`

My assumption is you have `String category =null;`

change is to `String category ="";`

Answer (score 0):

Variable that you have declared `String category` is either automatically or explicitly (in code) assigned as `null`.

So, Better to assign you variable `category` with `""`(Blank String). that will gives you a result what you are expecting..

> Sample Code Here is a [Demo To Demonstrate Your Problem](https://ideone.com/QB2iZ4)

```
String category = "";
categorty += "Appeltants Ronald";
System.out.prinln(category); //it will print Appeltants Ronald
```

Thank YOu.

Answer (score -2):

In the statement `conn =DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/","","");` you have not mentioned the name of the database and the `username,password` to access the database.

That's why there is no any connection made with the database and hence it is returning null.